Why $N$-doped 6H-SiC(0001) wafers is used for epitaxial growth graphene?
Why "$N$-doped" wafers is used for epitaxial growth graphene?
References:

https://www.nature.com/articles/nmat2382

https://doi.org/10.1126/science.1130681


